# breadth-first search traversal produces preorder?

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search, preorder

> Breadth-first search traversal of a tree produces a string with the
>   tree nodes in preorder.

Is the above statement a true assumption to make? If not, please advise with the exception case/s.

---

Ok, can now see that DFS (not BFS) and preorder are equivalent.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that the breadth-first search moving from the root, then the left node, then the right node?

Comment: we have to use breadth-first search: root, first level nodes, then second level nodes, and so on, moving from left to right at each level.